# FDF file doesn't work with URL

Tags: php, adobe, fdf

I am using a PHP script to generate FDF response and in that response the PDF template is supplied as a remote file "https://platweb-eur.qa.reachlocal.com/test/546_df50ab50418e1e925e81020815217649.pdf"
This is opening up the PDF template properly, but the fields are not getting populated.

While I am using local PDF template instead of file URL for the same pdf, fields's value were getting populated correctly.

So the issue is with remote file. Can anybody point me to what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Are the PDF and the FDF coming from the same domain?

Comment: In the actual scenario, the PDF and the FDF is coming from different domain but for testing I made both them to come from same domain but still it is not working.

Comment: Can you share a sample FDF... dummy values are acceptable.

Comment: @ joelgeraci : Thank you very much for your reply. Issue is resolved now. The issue was Mac Safari by default uses native reader instead of Adobe Reader. And thats why the data from FDF stream was not getting rendered. So while I forced Safari to use Adobe Reader in case of opening PDF, then the data from FDF rendered properly. One more thing we have to keep in mind that the domain name  have to be added in the "Extended Security" section of Adobe Reader property.

Comment: Wow. I'm surprised you go it to work at all with Safari. Nice job. The domain issue was where I was going for my first comment.